# Java test multiple computers on a network

Tags: java, networking, testing, udp, multicast

I am doing a project where multiple computers connect on a network send each other `UDP` packets on a multicast network.  I am able to test this out with a group of computers and my teammates when where running the same program on the same router.  However I want to write tests for this to be able to simulate this on a single computer when I am alone.  I don't care if all I am really doing it is sending it to myself but I want to know is there a testing way to simulate having multiple computer nodes in a network (with fake ip addresses') to send and receive pings from?  Or is this possible at all?

Comment: You can ping / send traffic to yourself.  But other than that, I don't think there is much else you can do.  Maybe set up some virtual machines running on your host computer assuming it can handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add more than one network interfaces to your testing computer then you may be able to test your stuff. One way of doing this maybe to add virtual interfaces. If you are using windows then you can add a virtual loopback network interface. Follow this link to setup that:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839013

For linux:

http://linuxconfig.org/configuring-virtual-network-interfaces-in-linux